# Tu vas devenir/être grand-mère

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

Are the both sentences below usual?

- Tu vas devenir grand-mère.
- Tu vas être grand-mère.

I have read the first one in a French learning tool. However, as "you are going to *be* a grandmother" seems to me more usual than "you are going to become a grandmother" in English, I wonder if the same happens in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On pourrait aussi très bien dire et dans le même sens :

- Tu vas *te retrouver* grand-mère

Dans *tu vas être grand-mère*, *être* est dans sa fonction dite de *copule*.
C'est à dire qu'**il n'apporte pas de sens**. Il ne sert qu'à mettre en relation les mots qui l'entourent, en général le sujet avec un attribut.

Eh bien il en va de même dans les phrases alternatives avec *devenir*, *se retrouver*...
Certains linguistes, souhaitant réserver la fonction de *copule* au seul verbe être disent ces verbes *essentiellement attributifs* mais cela revient presque au même, c'est à dire qu'ils font office de ligatures vides de sens.

*Tu vas être grand-mêre / Tu vas te retrouver grand-mère / Tu vas devenir grand-mère* (dans cet ordre relativement à mes préférences personnelles) disent donc **très précisément** la même chose.

Comment: I'm also interested to know which expressions are the most usual. Could you mention it in your answer?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista : Without any doubt, the simplest is always the most usual. And by far => *Tu vas **être**...*

Answer (score 3):

To my ear "être" sounds just a little more elevated or poetic, but they are both failry common formulations.

Comment: Oh? I agree that both are idiomatic, but to my ears, “être” sounds a little more ordinary, whereas “devenir” sounds slightly overdone.